# Sequence of logical OR in ES6/Unicode regular expression in Chrome ✗ vs Firefox ✓

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, google-chrome, unicode

Consider the following Unicode-heavy regular expression (emoji standing in for non-ASCII and extra-BMP characters):

```
''.match(/||/ug)
```

Firefox returns `[ "", "", "", "", "", "" ]` .

Chrome 52.0.2743.116 and Node 6.4.0 both return `null`! It doesn’t seem to care if I put the string in a variable and do `str.match(…)`, nor if I build a RegExp object via `new RegExp('||', 'gu')`.

(Chrome is ok with just ORing *two* sequences: `''.match(/|/ug)` is ok. It’s also ok with non-Unicode: `'aakkzzkkaa'.match(/aa|kk|zz/ug)` works.)

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a Chrome bug? The [ECMAScript compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Unicode_code_point_escapes) says I should be ok with Unicode regexps.

(PS: The three emoji used in this example are just stand-ins. In my application, they’ll be arbitrary but distinct strings. But I wonder if the fact that `''.match(/[]/ug)` works in Chrome is relevant?)

---

***Update*** Marked fixed on [12 April 2017](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=641091) in Chromium and downstream (including Chrome and Node).

Comment: Maybe I'm just conservative, but this would be easier to read with `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` or `A`, `B`, and `C`. Plus a lot of fonts still don't do all the emojis, so if someone is missing two of them they will see them both as a square -- or worse all three.

Comment: @CaptainMan the world speaks many languages, many of which are written with non-ASCII or (gasp!) extra-BMP characters. I’m using emoji as a standin for those characters. (Also I indicate in the post that the same example works with ASCII, so it’s a Unicode problem.) Updating title to emphasize Unicode.

Comment: I see now part of the point was for unicode (missed it at first). I still think more "vanilla" unicode characters would be better than emojis.

Comment: Note that `''.match(/[]/ug)` works in Chrome. Alternation *does* break the regex for some reason.

Comment: Folks. I want to use this code with, say, Tangut characters, new in Unicode 9. I think if this code breaks on emoji, it’ll break in my application.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. In my application, I’ll be searching for multi-character strings, so I can’t use `[a-z]`-like character sequences, but maybe the fact that that works but ORs don’t will give someone a hint as to the solution.

Comment: Check that regex is actually reading for the correct number of distinct characters. I think I've seen regex read emoji / unicode characters as two separate characters. I'll try to find a reference.

Comment: @Jecoms definitely—JavaScript’s UTF-16 representation means `''.length` evaluates to 6, not 3, and other shenanigans. However, I thought ES2015 and that trailing `u` regexp modifier would automagic everything into being Unicode-friendly ([reference](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#unicode)). Looking into this further…

Comment: `''.match(/||{1}/ug)` works. I say it's a bug.

Comment: @kennytm thanks!!! That increases my confidence that it’s a bug in Chrome-land. I’ll use that for now and file a bug report.

Comment: Filed… https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=641091

Comment: @AhmedFasih, without the "u"-flag it does also work in chrome *(52.0.2743.116)* for me

Comment: @Thomas well I’ll be a monkey’s uncle, you’re absolutely right. Thanks!

Comment: unless you use multiplier `''.match(/|{2}|/g)` -> null `{1}` and `{1,}` seem to work, I assume they are translated into `?` and `+`.  I assume without the "u"-flag `{2}` is interpreted as `\ud83c\udf66{2}`, wich would explain the behaviour. *SO doesn't print my regex right, when editing it ends with `{fruit}/g)`*

Comment: This is certainly the most amusing question I've read all day.

Comment: ES6 2014: According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), Chrome and Firefox support _codepoint's_ with the `//u` flag. Using codepoint units imply that internally, the regex _and_ target source are converted to either all UTF-8 or all UTF-32. Where in the regex the codepoint construct is `\u{xxxxxx}`. Literals, it says should be ok to put in classes _and_ can be quantified outside classes (see [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex)).  Until it's work out, don't use `//u`: handle utf-16 problems (surrogates).

Comment: Another data point: after transpiling the snippet using regexpu (or Babel/Traceur, which use regexpu) and executing it, the output matches that of Firefox. https://mothereff.in/regexpu#input=console.log(%0A++%27%F0%9F%8D%A4%F0%9F%8D%A6%F0%9F%8D%8B%F0%9F%8D%8B%F0%9F%8D%A6%F0%9F%8D%A4%27.match(/%F0%9F%8D%A4%7C%F0%9F%8D%A6%7C%F0%9F%8D%8B/ug)%0A)

Comment: @Thomas Your assumption is correct. See [https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex#impact-quantifiers](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex#impact-quantifiers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the `u` flag, your regexp works, and this is no wonder, since in the BMP (=no "u") mode it compares 16-bit "units" to 16-bit "units", that is, a surrogate pair to another surrogate pair.

The behaviour in the "u" mode (which is supposed to compare codepoints and not units) looks indeed like a Chrome bug, in the meantime you can enclose each alternative in a group, which seems to work fine:

```js
m = ''.match(/()|()|()/ug)
console.log(m)

// note that the groups must be capturing!
// this doesn't work:

m = ''.match(/(?:)|(?:)|(?:)/ug)
console.log(m)
```

And here's a quick proof that more than two SMP alternatives are broken in the `u` mode:

```js
// insert a whatever range 
// from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane
var range = '11300-1137F';

range = range.split('-').map(x => parseInt(x, 16))

var chars = [];
for (var i = range[0]; i <= range[1]; i++) {
    chars.push(String.fromCodePoint(i))
}

var str = chars.join('');

while(chars.length) {
    var re = new RegExp(chars.join('|'), 'u')
    if(str.match(re))
        console.log(chars.length, re);
    chars.pop();
}
```

In Chrome, it only logs the last two regexes (2 and 1 alts).

Answer (score 2):

> without the "u"-flag it does also work in chrome (52.0.2743.116) for me

well `u`-flag seems to be broken

> unless you use multiplier `''.match(/|{2}|/g)` -> null `{1}` and `{1,}` seem to work, I assume they are translated into ? and +. I assume without the "u"-flag `{2}` is interpreted as `\ud83c\udf66{2}`, wich would explain the behaviour.

just tested with `(?:){2}` this seems to work right. I guess this confirms my assumption about the multiplier.

here a quick fix for that:

```
//a utility I usually have in my codes
var replace = (pattern, replacement) => value => String(value).replace(pattern, replacement);

var fixRegexSource = replace(
    /[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]/g, 
    //"(?:$&)" //not sure wether this might still be buggy
    //that's why I convert it into the unicode-syntax,
    //this can't be misinterpreted
    c => `(?:\\u${c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)}\\u${c.charCodeAt(1).toString(16)})`
);

var fixRegex = regex => new RegExp(
    fixRegexSource(regex.source), 
    regex.flags.replace("u", "")
);
```

*sry, didn't come up with better function-names*